# Jinja2 set variable string outside loop without namespace

Tags: loops, scope, jinja2, shopify

I am trying to create a concatenated string off a loop and then set this to a variable I can then use outside the loop. I don't have access to namespace I am using an older version of Jinja2.

Here is what I have so far to illustrate what I am trying to do...

```
    {% set ab_cart_string = '' %}
    {% for item in cart_object %}

    VariantID = {{ item.variant_id }}
    Item Count = {{ item.quantity }}
    {% set ab_cart_string = ab_cart_string ~ item.variant_id ~ ':' ~ item.quantity ~ ',' %}
    String = {{ ab_cart_string }}

    {% endfor %}

    Url = {{ ab_cart_string|slice(0, -1) }}
```

**Expected Output:**

String = 27707915206755:1,28410722943075:1,

Url = 27707915206755:1,28410722943075:1

**Actual Output:**

String = 27707915206755:1,28410722943075:1,

Url =

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing variables outside the loop I built the string inside an  tag as the goal was to build a link.

Here I am looping through the products object and through each index I am adding a variant.id and a quantity to manually build a [cart link](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/cart/use-permalinks-to-preload-cart) in Shopify with the items that were last added from a user.

Then when there are multiple items in the loop I added a condition if not last loop we need to add a comma between the indexes. This way I was able to build the link properly per the permalinks to pre-load the cart in Shopify.

```
<a href="https://{{ event.domain }}/cart/
{%- set products = cart_object -%} 
{%- for product in products -%} 
    {{- product.variant_id -}}:{{- product.quantity -}}
    {%- if not loop.last -%},{%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}  
">CART LINK HERE</a>
```

Comment: So there where multiple problems with the code I first started with.
- I didn't need to have a variable to access outside of the loop
- Setting up the string with Jinja I found a better way to concatenate the string by placing it inside the <a> tag and then building the string from the loop
- Then adding the condition if not loop.last to add a comma between the loops for concatenation 
- I was also not targeting the right objects so my data was undefined